# How can I modify route table?

Tags: debian, route

I don't want to delete or add, just want to modify one rule.  Is there such a command or do I have to resort to Delete and Add ?

Computer is running Debian 6.

Comment: are you talking about the iptables? the firewall?

Comment: `ip route show` and `ip route help` should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from `ip rule help`, there is no replace:

```
$ ip rule help
Usage: ip rule [ list | add | del | flush ] SELECTOR ACTION
...
```

So you have to delete the rule then add its replacement. You can (and should) use the `pref` values to put the rules in the right order.

(Note that `ip route` does have a replace option, unlike `ip rule`. I'm not sure why they implemented it for one but not the other.)

Comment: You can modify a route table. `ip route help ... ip route { add | del | change | append | replace } ROUTE`

Comment: @mikeserv Indeed, you can modify a route, but not a rule. `ip route` v. `ip rule`.

Comment: OP asked ... "How can I modify route table?"

Comment: @mikeserv Indeed, and then stated he wanted to modify "one rule". OP accepted the answer, so I guess the title is in need of fixing. I'll put in a note about routes being different...

Comment: Good idea. And thanks for highlighting that for me too. I've never use `ip2` to directly alter `iptables` before. I've always used its own route config. Or is it `nftables` now? I don't even know.

Comment: @mikeserv `ip rule` is for policy routing (e.g., routing based on something other than destination address); it's different than `iptables` (indeed, almost completely unrelated).